# Как показать в консоли процент выполнения в той же строке?

Tags: php

В composer при загрузке пакета отображается прогресс в процентах, который заменяется в реалтайме. Совершенно не хочется писать проценты с новой строки. Каким образом это реализовать на PHP?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/console/helpers/progresshelper.html Хочу сделать примерно такое отображение

Comment: Либо используйте http://php.net/manual/en/book.ncurses.php, либо сдвигайте каретку назад при поощи "\r" и отображайте строку снова.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265288/update-command-line-output-i-e-for-progress

Comment: Всем спасибо, не стал разбираться на низком уровне. Просто использовал компонент, на который дал ссылку выше. Работает превосходно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так для справки уже было предложение сдвигать каретку выглядит это так

```
<?php

function progressBar($done, $total) {
    $write = '[';
    for($i=0; $i<$done; $i++) {
       if(floor($total) < $i) {
           $write .= ' ';
       } elseif(floor($total) == $i) {
           $write .= '>';
       } else {
           $write .= '=';
       }
    }
    $write .= ']';
    fwrite(STDOUT,"\r");
    fwrite(STDOUT, $write);
}

for($i=1; $i<10; $i++) {
  progressBar(10,$i);
  sleep(1);
}
```

а так да `ncurses` больше подойдёт, но помойму он по умолчанию не собран с php.

Comment: Спасибо, отлично работает.